# Using chainlink contracts and openzeppelin upgradeable contracts

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink, openzeppelin

I am using the VRFConsumerBaseV2 contract from the chainlink library. Now I'm trying to make my smart contracts updatable using the UUPS mechanism.
How can I adapt VRFConsumerBaseV2 for use in updatable contracts?

Perhaps there are ready-made solutions or you need to write your own wrapper for work

Comment: VRFConsumerBaseV2 is an abstract contract.  You need to use a client contract that implements AutomationCompatibleInterface [1].  The client contract that you write can then be used in a proxy pattern. Not the VRFConsumerBaseV2 abstract contract directly.

[1] https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/compatible-contracts